# Obfuscating Android library projects

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, andengine, library-project

I'm using AndEngine and two AndEngine extensions, for a total of 3 library projects. I really wish that I could obfuscate and optimize these library projects to improve application size, but I haven't seen anywhere how to do that with library projects.

Does anyone know what the `Proguard` configuration to do this is?

Answer (score 2):

When Application is compiled, all *.java files in references Library Projects are compiled into Application's `bin/classes` folder. And obfuscation step is done using .class files in this folder. This means that all referenced Library Projects are automatically obfuscated when you obfuscate your application.

Comment: However, I think I've encountered proguard error 1 when doing this.